# Use MFC classes in console application

Tags: automation, mfc, console, console-application

I loaded class of an application from typelib wizard in MFC project for software automation and I have written many code in console application and in my code I need to use this classes. How I can use this classes in console application or transfer my code from console application to MFC project to use this classes.

Answer (score 3):

I used following code for opening console in MFC project and copy other code directly to MFC project. my error was only because of `cout` and `cin`.

```
if (AllocConsole())
{
    FILE *fpstdin = stdin, *fpstdout = stdout, 
    *fpstderr = stderr;

    freopen_s(&fpstdin, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen_s(&fpstdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen_s(&fpstderr, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
}
```